# Is value of ebp register always multiple of 8?

Tags: gcc, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I am new to reverse engineering. Whenever I disassemled a program, I always found that value of `ebp` register be *multiple of 8.*

> Is value of `ebp` register always *multiple of 8* or just my observation?

Comment: for aligning the stack [Why does the compiler allocate more than needed in the stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37770751/995714)

Comment: As a side note, on Windows x86 EBP register is aligned on 4 but it's not always a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 3):

For performance reasons, modern x64 calling conventions requires the stack to be aligned to 16 bytes.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

This is also the case for `GCC`s x86 calling convention.

I can assume this is relevant for `ebp`, not only `esp`.