# Why more stack are allocated by gcc in arm assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

I am trying to read the output of gcc written in ARM assembly.
The following output seems strange to me.

```
int succ (int *arr)
{
  return arr[0] + 1;
}

int main (int argc)
{
  int a[1] = { argc };
  return succ (a);
}
```

By compilation command `gcc -fno-inline -O2 -S`, the following assembly program is generated.
I omit the out put about `succ` because it is not related to my question (just for stop elimination of unused variable `a`).

```
    .global main
    .type   main, %function
main:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    str     lr, [sp, #-4]!
    sub     sp, sp, #12
    add     r3, sp, #8
    str     r0, [r3, #-4]!
    mov     r0, r3
    bl      succ
    add     sp, sp, #12
    @ sp needed
    ldr     pc, [sp], #4
    .size   main, .-main
```

This `main` function seem to allocate 3 byte for local array `a` (sub sp, sp, #12).
But my C program allocate just one element of int for `a`.
Other temporal values don't seem to use stack.
Why this program require more stack volume than I expected?

My gcc version is 4.8.5. I tried in raspbian in rasberry-pi 3.

**UPDATED**
When I modified the length of array `a` to 2 (`int a[2} = {argc, argc}`), the volume doesn't changed (just 3 byte).
For length 3 (`int a[3} = {argc, argc, argc}`), 5 byte are allocated in stack.

It is curious to me.

Comment: [Stack allocation, why the extra space?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9862017/995714), [Why does the compiler allocate more than needed in the stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37770751/995714), [Why gcc disassembler allocating extra space for local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20865235/995714), [Why more memory is assigned to a local variable in stack than required in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18717162/995714)

Comment: the x86 and arm backends are two separate things.

Comment: `sub sp, sp, #12` "allocates" 12 bytes, or 3 words (ARM word = 32 bits = 4 bytes). 1 byte = 8 bits on pretty much everything what you can currently meet in real world (aside some museum or intentional obscurity).

Comment: Also, [Why AACPS requires 8 byte stack alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282466/why-procedure-call-standard-for-the-arm-architecture-aapcs-requires-sp-to-be).  Indeed making `succ` static changes things considerably.

Comment: Making it `static` gives the compiler the hint that it will not call external functions and a stack frame is not needed (to save `lr`).  The compiler also tries to keep your array 64bit aligned.  The array is more efficient if access starts at 64bits.  If you are concerned, compile with `-Os` or use other code generation options.

Answer (score 0):

I saw something like this the other day too.  I suspect that what is going on is that it has put lr on the stack.  It needs to align that to a 64 bit boundary so it needs 4 more bytes on the stack.  Then it needs 4 bytes for  a, and needs to align that so adds 4 bytes on the stack, not realizing that lr plus a was all they needed to allocate.

I will have to see if I can reproduce this differently from how you are causing it.

Comment: `main: frame = 8` <-- this could be a hint ?